# Suppose $d(x,y)=2^{-\Delta(x,y)}$ is a metric on the set of all infinite binary sequences. Show that a set is open

Tags: real-analysis

The set in question is $[a]:=\{x\in 2^\mathbb{N}, a$ is the beginning of x$\}$.

I don't understand how the given metric should be used in the proof that $[a]$ is open.

Comment: Should $s$ be replaced by $a$ in your definition?  Otherwise, what's $s$?

Comment: $\Delta(x,y)$ is the first index at which $x$ and $y$ differ (if $x\neq y$)?

Answer (score 3):

I’m assuming that $\Delta(x,y)$ is defined only for $x\ne y$, in which case it is

$$\Delta(x,y)=\min\{k\in\Bbb N:x_k\ne y_k\}\;,$$

and that the actual definition of $d$ is that

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=y\\
2^{-\Delta(x,y)},&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Further, $a$ must be a finite sequence $a=\langle a_0,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, with each $a_k\in\{0,1\}$. Then

$$[a]=\left\{x\in 2^{\Bbb N}:x_k=a_k\text{ for all }k\le n\right\}\;,$$

and we want to show that $[a]$ is open. Let $x\in[a]$; we want to find an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq[a]$, where $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the open $d$-ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred at $x$. In other words, we want to choose $\epsilon$ in such a way that if $d(x,y)<\epsilon$, then $y_k=a_k$ for each $k\le n$. That happens if and only if $y_k=x_k$ for each $k\le n$, which in turn means that $\Delta(x,y)>n$ (or $y=x$). Can you see how to choose $\epsilon>0$ so that if $0<d(x,y)<\epsilon$, then $\Delta(x,y)>n$?

Comment: I think this question is a little too advanced for me, why are we using open $d-ball$? And why do we want $\Delta(x,y)>n?$

Comment: @grayQuant: A set $U$ in a metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$ is open if and only if for each $x\in U$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$; I’m simply applying this definition in the present case, in which the set $U$ is $[a]$ and the space is $\left\langle 2^{\Bbb N},d\right\rangle$. \\ We want $y$ to be in $[a]$, so we want $y_k=a_k$ for each $k\le n$. Since $x_k=a_k$ for each $k\le n$, this means that we want $y_k=x_k$ for each $k\le n$. Look at the definition of $\Delta(x,y)$: if $x_{\Delta(x,y)}\ne y_{\Delta(x,y)}$, so we can’t have $\Delta(x,y)\le n$.

Comment: I understand what you're doing but not enough to see what $\epsilon$ should be.

Comment: @grayQuant: Suppose that I suggest taking $\epsilon$ to be of the form $\frac1{2^m}$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$; can you choose $m$ in a way that guarantees that if $0<d(x,y)<\frac1{2^m}$, then $\Delta(x,y)>n$?

Comment: $m<|x-y|$ would guarantee $d(x,y)<\frac{1}{2^m}$

Comment: @grayQuant: What do you mean by $|x-y|$? That doesn’t appear to make sense. Remember, $x$ and $y$ are infinite binary sequences. Go back to the definition of $d$. If $x\ne y$, $d(x,y)=2^{-\Delta(x,y)}$. If $0<d(x,y)<\frac1{2^m}$, then $2^{-\Delta(x,y)}<2^{-m}$. How can you choose $m$ so that if $2^{-\Delta(x,y)}<2^{-m}$, then $\Delta(x,y)>n$?

Comment: $m<\Delta(x,y)$?

Comment: @grayQuant: How could that possibly help? It’s clear that $m$ has to depend in some way on the $n$ that you’re given. In fact the inequality $m<\Delta(x,y)$ is equivalent to the inequality $2^{-\Delta(x,y)}<2^{-m}$, so you need to figure out how to choose $m$ so that if $m<\Delta(x,y)$, then $\Delta(x,y)>n$. (And when it’s put in this language, it should be very easy to see just how big $m$ has to be.)

Comment: so $m>n$? but still $< \Delta(x,y)$

Comment: @grayQuant: Slow down and work it out. Suppose that we take $\epsilon=2^{-n}$. Then if $0<d(x,y)<\epsilon$, we know that $d(x,y)=2^{-\Delta(x,y)}$ (since $x\ne y$) and $2^{-\Delta(x,y)}<2^{-n}$ (since $d(x,y)<\epsilon$). That means that $\Delta(x,y)>n$, which in turn means that $x_k=y_k$ for every $k\le n$. And as we’ve already seen, that means that $y_k=a_k$ for every $k\le n$ and hence that $y\in[a]$. In other words, $B(x,2^{-n})\subseteq[a]$.